# If $m$ is the smallest positive integer such that $T^m = 0_v$, then $m \leq \dim(V)$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a vector space and $T \in L(v)$. Prove that

If $m$ is the smallest positive integer such that $T^m = 0_v$, then $m \leq \dim(V)$

I have no idea how to prove this.

Comment: In addition to the below answers one can prove this quickly using Jordan Normal Form.

Comment: @Travis: normally you wouldn't know about the JNF before knowing this result.

Comment: Four answers have appeared (including mine) and so far I am the only person who has up-voted the question.

Comment: @MichaelHardy: Four answers have appeared (including mine) and so far I am the only person who has up-voted one of the answers. Also I'm sure I've answered many more questions than I ever upvoted, should I feel guilty?

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen Yes, I agree that is likely, and part of why I didn't write up the remark as an answer, but I think the point still merits a comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose that the smallest such $m$ is greater than $k = \dim V$. Pick a vector $v$ such that $T^{m-1} v \ne 0$. Then $v, Tv, T^2v, \ldots, T^{m-1} v$ are all nonzero. (If any are zero, then all subsequent ones are!).

I claim that these are  linearly independent.

Suppose $\sum c_i T^i v = 0$.

Apply $T^{m-1}$ to both sides to conclude that $c_0 = 0$.

Then apply $T^{m-2}$ to both sides to conclude that $c_1 = 0$.

Continue in this way.

Conclusion: the $m$ vectors are independent, so $\dim V \ge m > k = \dim V$, a contradiction.

**Improved version, avoiding contradiction:**

Since $T^{m-1} \ne 0$, there's some vector $v$ with $T^{m-1} v \ne 0$.

Then $v, Tv, T^2v, ..., T^{m-1} v$ are all nonzero. (If any are zero, then all subsequent ones are!).

I claim that these are  linearly independent.

Suppose 
$$
\sum_{i=0}^{m-1} c_i T^i v = 0.$$

Applying $T^{m-1}$ to both sides gives
$$
\sum_{i=0}^{m-1} c_i T^{i+m-1} v = 0 \text{, and since $T^r = 0$ for $r \ge m$,} \\
\sum_{i=0}^{0} c_i T^{i+m-1} v = 0 \text{, i.e}\\
c_0 T^{m-1} v = 0, 
$$ 
hence $c_0 = 0$.

Applying smaller and smaller powers of $T$ to both sides, we can conclude that $c_1, c_2$, etc., are all zero. This lets us conclude that the $m$ vectors are all linearly independent.

Since the number of elements of a linearly independent set is no greater than the dimension, we have that $m \le \dim V$.

Comment: Fixed. Just noticed that myself as I was writing out a non-contradiction proof...

Comment: I cleaned up the notation somewhat, in marticular changing $dim V$ to $\dim V$ (coded as \dim V) and other improvements, all standard usage.  Then you changed it back again and I fixed it again.  Some more work is needed.

Comment: Thanks, Michael. I always forget about "\dim". I've edited a few other bits as well.

Answer (score 2):

Most of the time there isn't any positive integer $m$ such that $T^m=0$, in which case talking about the smallest such $m$ makes no sense. I will assume however that one is supposed to be in the (exceptional) circumstance that such $m$ exists (such $T$ are called nilpotent), and $m$ is then chosen to be as small as possible.

This means there is a vector $v$ such that $T^m\cdot v=0$ (obviously) but $T^{m-1}\cdot v\neq0$ (since if there were no such $v$ then $m$ would not be minimal). This means that $v\notin\ker(T^{m-1})$ and so $v$ witnesses that $\ker(T^{m-1})$ is *strictly* contained in $\ker(T^m)=V$. The idea is to continue the sequence of subspaces $\ker(T^m),\ker(T^{m-1}),\ker(T^{m-2}),\ldots\ker(T),\ker(T^0)=\{0\}$ and to show that each one is *strictly* contained in its predecessor; this will give $m$ steps where the dimension drops, so that the initial dimension $\dim V$ must have been at least$~m$. That each space is contained in its predecessor is obvious from the definition of kernels; as witnesses for the fact that the inclusion is strict, one can use images of the vector$~v$.

Comment: I like this proof, but if I were teaching linear algebra, I think I'd ask the question once, leading the student towards the answer that I gave here; then, a couple of weeks later, when students are comfortable with subspaces and inclusions, etc., I'd ask the question again and lead them towards the answer you gave, which is of a style likely to be useful elsewhere in their studies.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\;v\in V\;$ be such that $\;T^{m-1}\neq 0\;$ (why such $\;v\;$ exists?), then

$$\{v\,,\,Tv\,,\,T^2v\,,\ldots\,,T^{m-1}v\}\;\;\text{is linearly independent, since:}$$

$$a_0v+a_1Tv+\ldots+a_{m-1}T^{m-1}v=0\implies 0=T(0)=a_0Tv+a_1T^2v+\ldots+a_{m-1}T^mv$$

But $\;T^mv=0\;$  , so in fact we have

$$a_0Tv+\ldots+a_{m-2}T^{m-1}v=0$$

Apply $\;T\;$ again and get a shorter trivial combination. After some times (how many?), you get that $\;a_0T^{m-1}v=0\implies a_0=0\;$ .

Inductively, $\;a_0=a_1=\ldots a_{m-1}=0\;$ and we're done

Finally, remember that in an $\;n$-dimensional space there can't be more than $\;n\;$ vectors linearly independent.

Comment: There is a $v$ missing in the condition for $v$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $T^{m-1}v\ne0$, there must be some vector $v$ for which $T^{m-1}v\ne0$, and that entails that $v\ne0,\ Tv\ne0,\ T^2 v\ne0,\ldots,T^{m-1} v\ne0$.

If you can show that $v,\ Tv,\ T^2v,\ \ldots,T^{m-1}v$ are linearly independent, then you can conclude $\dim V\ge m$ since there are $m$ vectors in that set.  If those vectors are linearly dependent, then you have
$$
c_0 v + c_1 Tv + c_2 T^2 v + \cdots + c_{m-1} T^{m-1} v=0
$$
for some scalars $c_0,\ldots,c_m$, not all $0$.  Consequently
$$
T(c_0 v + c_1 Tv + c_2 T^2 v + \cdots + c_{m-1} T^{m-1} v) = T0= 0,
$$
so
$$
c_0 Tv + c_1 T^2 v + \cdots + c_{m-2} T^{m-1}v + c_{m-1}T^m v=0, 
$$
but the last term on the left above is $0$, so
$$
c_0 Tv + c_1 T^2 v + \cdots + c_{m-2} T^{m-1}v =0.
$$
Then in the same way you can conclude that
$$
c_0 T^2 v + c_2 T^3 v + \cdots + c_{m-3}T^{m-1}v=0,
$$
and then that
$$
c_0 T^3 v+ c_1 T^4 v + \cdots + c_{m-4} T^{m-1}v=0,
$$
and so on, until you have $c_0 T^{m-1}v=0$.  Since $T^{m-1}v\ne 0$, this implies $c_0=0$.  Then you have
$$
c_1Tv+c_2 T^2v+\cdots+c_{m-1}T^{m-1}v=0,
$$
and then do the same thing with $Tv$ that we did with $v$ above, and conclude that $c_1=0$.  Then keep going in the same way to show that $c_0=c_1=\cdots=c_{m-1}=0$.

Finally, conclude that $v,\ Tv,\ T^2v,\ldots,\ T^{m-1}v$ are linearly independent.

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert but I'll try to sketch an idea. Let $\dim(V)=n$, and let $\mathbb{O}=0_{L(V)}$.
Since $T$ is an endomorphism and $T^m=\mathbb{O}$, we must have $\ker(T)\neq\{0_V\}$, because otherwise you would have that $T$ is invertible and so $\mathbb{I}=T^{-m}\circ T^m=T^{-m}\circ \mathbb{O}=\mathbb{O}$ which is absurd. So, take $v\in\ker(T)$. $T^k(v)=(T^{k-1}\circ T)(v)=T^{k-1}(T(v))=T^{k-1}(0_V)=0_V$ so $v$ is also in $\ker(T^k)$ for any $k$. This means that $\ker(T)\subseteq\ker(T^2)\subseteq\ker(T^3)\subseteq\dots \subseteq\ker(T^m)=V$. Moreover, if $\ker(T)\subseteq im(T)$, that means that for $v\neq 0_V,v\in\ker(T)$ there exists $w$ such that $v=T(w)$ so that $T(v)=T^2(w)=0_V$: this implies that $w\in\ker(T^2)$ but $w\notin\ker(T)$, so the above chain is really
\begin{equation}
\ker(T)\subset\ker(T^2)\subset\ker(T^3)\subset\dots \subset\ker(T^m)=V
\end{equation}
(If otherwise $im(T)\subseteq \ker(T)$, what happens?)

Passing to the dimension of these subspaces,
\begin{equation}
\dim(\ker(T))<\dim(\ker(T^2))<\dim(\ker(T^3))<\dots<\dim(\ker(T^m))=n
\end{equation}
That means that there are $m$ positive integers $d_1,\dots,d_m$ such that
\begin{equation}
0<d_1<d_2<d_3<\dots<d_m=n
\end{equation} 
That shows that $m\leq n$.
In fact, the best possible situation is when you have $d_k=k$; in that case $m=n$.

Comment: It seems like you are after a proof a lot like the one I gave, but you got confused along the way. Certainly $v\in\ker(T)$ is not a good choice, since higher images by $T$ of $v$ that you write down will all be$~0$. You may work your way backwards taking pre-images, but this takes hard work, and your initial $v$ may not be the right choice to make it work. Also after $v=T(w)$ certainly $T(w)\neq 0$, so you're going astray.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get the point- the idea was to show that $\ker(T^i)$ is strictly contained in $\ker(T^{i+1})$ for each $i$ up to $m$. In my answer I did not handle the general case, only the case $\ker(T)\subseteq im(T)$, but in general you can show that $\ker(T)\cap im(T)$ is not $0$ because otherwise you would have $T(im(T))=im(T)$ and that contradicts the hypothesis that $T^m=\mathbb{O}$...

Comment: Taking $v\in\ker(T)$ was only to show that $\ker(T)\subseteq\ker(T^2)\subseteq...\subseteq\ker(T^m)$. To show that they are strictly contained one in the other you can take preimages of any vector in $\ker(T)\cap im(T)$.

Comment: In the example above, I take $v\in\ker(T)$ with the condition $v\neq 0$. Since $\ker(T)\subseteq im(T)$, there exists $w$ such that $T(w)=v$. So $T(w)\neq 0$, i.e. $w\notin\ker(T)$ but $T^2(w)=T(v)=0$ i.e. $w\in\ker(T^2)$...i don't see the confusion you are pointing at...could you please explain it to me?

Comment: One confusion is that instead of $T^2(w)=T(v)=0$ in your comment, your answer says $T(w)=T^2(v)=0_V$

Comment: Thank you Marc, it was a typo, i corrected it. Do you think that now it could work?

Comment: Well, it looks better. But the fact remains that you are reasoning only for a special case $\ker(T)\subseteq im(T)$ that has no particular reason to be true, and that you are jumping from the $2$-step to the $m$-step case (you only showed $\ker(T)\subset\ker(T^2)$ to be strict, not the other inclusions) without justification. At the very least, you need to formulate a statement to be proved by induction. But please read my first answer, and check whether this does not say exactly what you wanted to say. Note that my $v$ _avoids_ being in any kernel, while it can.

Comment: True, this is not a proof, just a sketch. I think the idea was parallel to yours, but I actually need to be less vague.

Answer (score 0):

Although I wouldn't personally consider this a very good answer (using too heavy artillery for the proof of a relatively simple fact), it may be noted that a proof using the Cayley-Hamilton theorem is also possible.

Since it is (apparently) given that $T$ is nilpotent (there exists $k$ with $T^k=0$), all eigenvalues$~\lambda$ (in an algebraically closed field) of$~T$ satisfy $\lambda^k=0$ and hence $\lambda=0$. The characteristic polynomial then can only be $X^n$ where $n=\dim(V)$, so $T^n=0$ by the Cayley-Hamilton theorem, and $m\leq n=\dim(V)$.